# Chinese Remainder Theorem proof using maximal ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

I am trying to prove Generalized Chinese Remainder Theorem based on the following hint.

The statement is: $\{Q_i\}$ is a set of coprime ideals of a commutative ring $R$ and $\phi : R \to \prod_{i} R/Q_i$ is a mapping obtained from projections. Prove that $\phi$ is surjective.

**Hint:** If $I$ is a maximal ideal than it can contain at most one of the $Q_i$.

I thought of trying to prove it by contradiction: like taking an element that has no preimage and then prove that preimage of the ideal generated by this element is maximal (and also contains the $ker(\phi) = \cap_{i} Q_i$). Something like this. But failed actually :)

Comment: The assertion is false if the set $\{ Q_i \}$ is infinite. For example $\mathbb Z \to \prod_{p \in \mathbb P} \mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$ is not surjective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the set is finite, the hint tells you to localize at any maximal ideal. Then use that finite products are the same as finite direct sums and localization commutes with arbitrary direct sums.

After localizing at a maximal ideal, the surjecitivity is trivial, hence the result follows, since we can test surjectivity locally.

Just another comment: This is a proof for the fact that localization does not commute with arbitrary products. Because if it would, we could use the above proof to show surjecitivity of $\mathbb Z \to \prod_{p \in \mathbb P} \mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$, which is false.

Comment: Thank you! It's one more of your answers to my questions and I see that you have a very geometric attitude towards algebra. This is exactly what I need. May be you can recommend some good geometric (but serious) book on commutative algebra? (or any other part of algebra as this subject really lacks geometric view and it always a problem to find geometric intuitive interpretations).

Comment: Eisenbud's book uses geometry to motivate commutative algebra, but this book is very hard to read for a beginner.